# How do I sign out of the GitHub app on Android?

Tags: applications

I think I've looked everywhere but I don't see how to sign out of the GitHub app on Android. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give me the link to the GitHub app you're referring to? I can find around 20 on the Play store.

Comment: Oddly, the app I'm using seems to have disappeared from Android Play. Maybe GitHub withdrew it.

Comment: Try accessing the [Authorized applications](https://github.com/settings/applications) setting on the browser, then check if you can revoke the authorization.

Answer (score -2):

try cleaning app data from settings, then reboot. beware, it is going to open like the first time you opened it. don't recommend it if you have any data  saved on the app.

Comment: I tried that but wasn't logged out. Given that the app seems to have been withdrawn from the Play store, it is likely there's no way to logout.